# Google closure compiler gives error

Tags: javascript, security, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I'm using google closure compiler to obfuscate javascript code using this [website](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). When I use simple optimization this works but when I use advanced optimization it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.a is not a function

I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: [*"\[...\] code compiled with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS may not work with uncompiled code unless you take special steps to ensure interoperability. If you do not flag external functions and properties referenced in your code, Closure Compiler will inappropriately rename references in your code, causing mismatches between the names in your code and in the external code."*](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels?csw=1#advanced_optimizations)

Comment: It will be hard to determine the cause without looking at your code. If it's something short and safe to open source, feel free to paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read 
Restrictions for ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS section in this link
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations?hl=en